# bytesAvailable() of QTcpSocket returns a fixed value

Tags: qt, sockets

I have written a server using `QTcpSocket`. The server handles the POST request from client app. I use the content-length field to determine the end of the request body. The code is as follows:

```
    int length = 0;

    QString line = "";

    while(this->canReadLine())
    {
        line = this.readLine();

        if(line.contains("Content-Length"))
        {
            length = line.split(':')[1].toInt();
        }

        if(line == "\r\n")
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(; this.bytesAvailable() < length; ){}

    QString requestBody = this.readAll();
```

It works in my localhost. But when it is run on remote server, `bytesAvailable` always returns a fixed value: `0` or `2896`. Is there something wrong in my code or the network is causing that?

Comment: Maybe other application uses the same port?

Comment: Your test doesn't make sense. Why should the bytes currently available ever equal the length? You should just keep reading util you have the right length.

Comment: @Satus It's impossible. I choose a special port.

Comment: @EJP Is there a possible the inner buffer of QTcpSocket is full? So the follow bytes can't be count? I will try to keep reading util the right length.

Comment: @EJP The application works well on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bytesAvailable()` function only tells you how many bytes are in the internal buffer of `QTcpSocket`, it does not instruct it to look for more data coming across the network. Calling this function repeatedly is thus a pointless exercise and can cause your program to hang.

What you are trying to do is wait for more data to arrive. To do this, you must let your program go back to the event loop or call one of the blocking functions, like `waitForReadyRead()`

EDIT:
If you're using standard HTTP processing, also consider using `QNetworkAccessManager` along with `QNetworkReply` to simplify the data retrieval process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using QTcpSocket to write a HTTP server, so i have to handle this manually